# php foreach loop in form validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, foreach

I already got the form validation working, I just need to apply a CSS class to the input field to give it a red border when an error was triggered. There are 2 possible errors. Each one works fine individually but when both errors are triggered only one of the boxes get the border. Used this same code on another form but not in a function and it worked fine. What am I missing?

```
//function stackoverflow($pet, $grab, $errors_NaN)
...
...
//testing here to make sure all errors are in the array
    var_dump($errors_NaN);
        echo '<br />';
        foreach($errors_NaN as $error){
            echo $error . '<br />';
        }


        echo '<div class="edit_col3">';
        echo '<div class="formrow">';
        echo '<label for="weight">Weight</label>'; //no text validation
            echo '<input ';


            if (!empty($errors_NaN)) {
                foreach($errors_NaN as $error){
                    if($error == 'weight_NaN'){
                        echo 'class="edit_mfwa"';
                                              //this triggers if ONLY weight_NaN is in the array but not if both weight_NaN and age_NaN
                    }
                    else {
                        echo 'class="weight"'; 
                    }
                }
            }
            elseif (empty($errors_NaN)){
                echo 'class="weight"';
            }


            echo ' type="text" name="weight" value="' . $grab['weight'] . '" id="weight" />';
            echo '<div class="pet_units">lbs</div>';
            echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
        echo '</div>';// end form row

        echo '<div class="formrow">';
        echo '<label for="age">Age</label>';  //no text validation
            echo '<input ';


            if (!empty($errors_NaN)) {
                foreach($errors_NaN as => $error){
                    if($error == 'age_NaN'){
                        echo 'class="edit_mfwa"';
                                              //this triggers properly in both situation
                    }
                    else {
                        echo 'class="age"';
                    }
                }
            } 
            elseif (empty($errors_NaN)) {
                echo 'class="age"';
            }


            echo ' type="text" name="age" value="' .  $grab['age'] . '" id="age" />';
            echo '<div class="pet_units">years</div>';
            echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
        echo '</div>'; //end form row
```

Commented in a few places where the problem seems to be happening

Comment: have you ever checked the generated html?

Comment: Check my awnser, I edited it to a better sample :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both weight_NaN and age_NaN are in your array, you will trigger both (so also using your else statement: echo 'class="weight"';

I would say, if you use as following:

```
        $useClass = 'class="weight"';

        if (!empty($errors_NaN)) {
            foreach($errors_NaN as $error){
                if($error == 'weight_NaN'){
                    $useClass 'class="edit_mfwa"';
                }
            }
        }

        echo $useClass;
```

It will work proper :)!

Comment: glad to help, as long you know what you did wrong to learn from it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo '<div class="edit_col3">';
echo '<div class="formrow">';
echo '<label for="weight">Weight</label>'; //no text validation
echo '<input class="'.(in_array('weight_NaN', $errors_NaN)?'edit_mfwa':'weight';
echo '" />';
```

Comment: Dont know ternary operators very well so wasnt able to adjust your code. Have one extra ( in there I wasnt sure what to do with.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
if (!empty($errors_NaN)) {
            foreach($errors_NaN as => $error){
                if($error == 'age_NaN'){
                    echo 'class="edit_mfwa"';
                                          //this triggers properly in both situation
                }
                else {
                    echo 'class="age"';
                }
            }
        } 
        elseif (empty($errors_NaN)) {
            echo 'class="age"';
        }
```

with this:

```
if (!empty($errors_NaN)) {
                foreach($errors_NaN as $error){
                    if($error == 'age_NaN'){
                        echo 'class="edit_mfwa"';
                                              //this triggers properly in both situation
                    }
                    else {
                        echo 'class="age"';
                    }
                }
            }
```

To see where u made mistake:  `foreach($errors_NaN as => $error){` -> `foreach($errors_NaN as $error){`

Comment: Good catch. That was a typo I made while editing the code in stackoverflow. Wasnt a problem in my actual code.

Comment: yeah well i hope u find solution